# AWS Backup EBS volume with a name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudWatch Rule setup to backup some EBS volumes. It executes fine, but in the EC2 window under snapshots the name column is not populated.

Anyone know how I can modify the rule to give a name to each EBS snapshot when the rule executes?

Comment: According to my answer - what you use to backup that EBS? Lambda? Then I'll provide more explanation on how you can copy Name tag.

Comment: I'm using a Cloudwatch rule that runs automatically on a schedule to create the backup of the EBS volume.

Comment: Creeping on my old question but AWS Lifecycle manager is a much better way to go now.

Answer (score 0):

What you see there it's just **[Tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-resources)** value for Tag key: **Name**

On [creating snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSnapshot.html) - you can specify tags, so just copy **Name** tag from original EBS.